# How to retrieve an image that is split into a grid from urls and combine them into one?

Tags: python, image, url

How would you retrieve a image that is split into 6 separate images from six different urls and combine them into a single on.

So there is a image split into a grid like this under, where each image is on a separate url. The url does not end with a `.jpg`, `.png` or any file type.

```
|-----------|-----------|
|  Col 0    |   Col 1   |
|  Row 0    |   Row 0   |          |-----------|
|-----------|-----------|          |           |
|  Col 0    |   Col 1   |          |   New     |
|  Row 1    |   Row 1   |   ==>>   |   single  |
|-----------|-----------|          |   image   |
|  Col 0    |   Col 1   |          |-----------|
|  Row 2    |   Row 2   |
|-----------|-----------|
```

I have seen some separate issues that I could combine to fix this problem, but I was not able to get them to work together. This is supposed to work for several hundred pictures.

Comment: It depends on the images and where they are and how they are named and what their format is.

Comment: The url is predictable and the format is `.jpg` I think.

Comment: Use PIL the Python Imaging Library module. First create a empty image the size of the the size sub-images combined, then read and paste each of these sub-image files in an place them at six different locates as determined by their size. If you have written something like that and are having problems, then you must post the code in your question and describe the exactly what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have provided no images or links, I am putting some sample images here that I can download and use in my answer:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from imageio import imread, imwrite

# Read the 6 images, taking just the first 3 RGB channels of each (discarding any alpha channel)
im1 = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5Cyb.png')[...,:3]
im2 = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYPxr.png')[...,:3]
im3 = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/APnAq.png')[...,:3]
im4 = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy232.png')[...,:3]
im5 = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIXhf.png')[...,:3]
im6 = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsQnX.png')[...,:3]

# Vertically stack 3 images to make left column, and 3 more to make right column
Lcol = np.vstack((im1,im2,im3))
Rcol = np.vstack((im4,im5,im6))

# Horizontally stack 2 columns to make result
result = np.hstack((Lcol,Rcol))

# Save result to disk
imwrite('result.jpg', result)
```

**Result**

[image]